# Use SharePoint Designer to UpdateList from external source

Tags: 2007, web-services

My current environment is set up from a SP teamsite that I have current admin rights on. I want to have a SQL Server external DB update my SP list on my teamsite dynamically. My idea is that I am creating a WebApp GUI for people to update the SQL Server database from views that is the exact copy of the data in the SP list. When a user updates the data, my question is can I use SP designer to have the SP List on the teamsite to point to the SQL server external DB thats connected to the WebApp GUI, so that when the tables are updated the list is automatically updated. I believe Visual Studio could easily do that with creating a custom webpart, but my question is could Sharepoint designer 2007 accomplish this.

Let me know if I made my question clear enough.

Answer (score 2):

I've done it the other way, SharePoint lists update an external SQL Server database with Nintex Workflow execute SQL actions.  To do it the other way, SQL Server to Sharepoint, you'd want to look into using the Business Data Catalog, assuming you're using SharePoint Server 2007 Enterprise.

Comment: using the business data catalog webpart list, would I have to have the tables in my external SQL server DB as a list format, or is there a way to write queries in the webpart to populate it in the list format?

Comment: also, if instead was wanted to allow the user to update the list directly from SP, following the way you say you don it previously. could you go more in details of how you would accomplish that

Comment: Once the external DB has an ADF created and brought into the farm in the Shared Service Provider, you can use web parts to interact with the data, create data sources against it in Sharepoint Designer and create data view web parts based off of the data source or the BDC.

Comment: Nintex Workflow is a thrid party workflow tool for Sharepoint.  In it, it has an action to execute SQL.  When it's configured, you can insert and update external SQL server data when new items are created or edited.

Comment: ? so for the original action I was pursuing, the external DB has to be brought into the SP farm?

Comment: Is that third party tool the only way to do that route?

Comment: Yes, it isn't the data per se, it's a means of letting Sharepoint know where and how to interact with the external system.  Here is an overview of the BDC, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms551230(v=office.12).aspx.

Comment: Was your yes for the SP farm question or for the third party tool question? Also lets say instead of using SP designer I was using Visual Studio 2008, would it  be possible to do all of this without using the Business Data catalog webpart and without the third party tool?

Comment: Yes was to the data import, there are thrid party tools to help build the ADFs required for importation into the BDC.  Lightning Tools has a quality application for that.  Re VS, I don't know to be honest, I'm not a developer.

Comment: data import? thats kind of on both instances, so still not sure which one you're referring to, for the original action I was pusueing to update SP list based on external DB I would have to have the external DB brought into the SP farm?

Comment: The ADF file acts as the "import" in that it tells Sharepoint how to interact with the data on the external database.  The data still resides externally.  The web parts display the data from the remote source.

Comment: Do you mean a mdf file, not sure of what an adf file is?

Comment: No, I mean an ADF file, Application Definition File.  I'd review the link above that explains what the BDC is.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms563661.aspx is a good link too.

Answer (score 0):

I would create an external content type using SP Designer to connect to the SQL DB from SharePoint.

You can then update SQL using your WebApp GUI and the view in SharePoint would be automatically updated.

This is assuming that your data is held in a custom database, and not in your SharePoint content database.

Comment: external content type only in 2010